# How consider input string as PST time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have to consider an input string as a PST time and then convert it to UTC time. I am using joda to do the same. However joda is considering the input as system time and my server is running in UTC time zone. I am 100% sure that input string is for PST time. here is my code -

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
pstTime = formatter.parseDateTime(time);
utcTime = pstTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(timeZone));
```

If I set system time to PST it works just fine. But since my server is on UTC how do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add this -

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use `TimeZone`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
```